# Asp.net radiobuttonlist control padding text

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I use ASP.net 4.5.
I have this asp code:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdHeaders" cssClass="radio-inline" runat="server"  RepeatLayout="Flow" RepeatDirection="Vertical">
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

And this code behind that creates radio buttons list.

```
    private void CreateRadioButtons(List<string> headers)
    {
        rdHeaders.Items.Add(Properties.ErrorStrings.DefaultHeader);
        rdHeaders.SelectedIndex = 0;

        foreach (string header in headers)
            rdHeaders.Items.Add(header);

        XMLHeaders.Visible = true;
    }
```

And here how it looks on the browser:

[image]

As you can see I have overlap radiobuttons on the text.

**UPDATE**
Here is definition radio-inline class:

```
.radio-inline{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-weight: 400;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

My question is how can I move left text to prevent overlap?

Comment: Can you add the `radio-inline` CSS class to your question?

Comment: @NicholasV. see please update